# Marrying Someone on Skyrim PS3

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have the amulet of Mara but when I go to talk to maramal about a wedding nothing shows up. WHY is that.

Comment: As said by @amaranth, you usually acquire the amulet, go talk to Maramal and then you need to propose to someone. When you'll have found someone and he will have asked you to organize the wedding, you will be able to speak to Maramal about it. (If I remember it right that was something in that order)

Comment: I have  tried to talk to him but nothing shows up about being able to purchase the amulet or about a wedding. My characters gender is female if that has anything to do with it

Comment: But what happens if you talk to someone you want to marry? It sounds like your game might be messed up, but you might as well try marrying someone.

Comment: Also, what if you try dropping the Amulet of Mara and then talk to Maramal without the amulet in your inventory?

Comment: I have tried to talk to someone to marry them but nothing happens. I will try dropping the amulet

Comment: I just checked, and the option you want when talking to Maramal is, "I wanted to know more about the temple of Mara." It shouldn't matter whether you have an amulet of Mara, or at least it didn't for me. If that dialog option isn't there, and neither is anything mentioning marriage, then I don't know how to fix it. Can you go back to an older saved game?

Comment: You must be scary in real life. "I HAVE A WEDDING RING GO ON MARRY ME"

Answer (score 2):

You need to have someone agree to marry you before you can arrange a wedding.

To have someone agree to marry you, you must first talk to Maramal about marriages. Then you must wear an amulet of Mara and talk to a potential spouse. If they like you enough and is available, they will agree to be married.

Only then will the dialogue about a Wedding show up. You do not need a Amulet of Mara when talking with Maramal.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the only way to marry someone is, while wearing the amulet of Mara, walk up to that certain someone special and they will give you a quest to complete. Once it's completed, talk to he/she and go get married.